# When are these iAd delegate methods called?

Tags: ios, delegates, iad

Ok I am am using the delegate method

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner

Being only test ads I cant test when it is called. I know it is called when the ad is closed with the X as i can click that in the test ad and it calls the delegate method. My question is, is it also called when the user interacts with the ad i.e clicks to download the advertised app or only when closed?

Also im trying understand the revenue from iAds.

if an ad is displayed in the bannerView on my app does that generate any revenue?

if an ad banner is clicked to load an ad does that generate any revenue?

if an ad banner is clicked to load an ad into full screen does count towards the CTR?

if an ad is loaded an interacted with does that generate any revenue and does that count towards the CTR?

Thanks

Comment: What does the iAds documentation say?

Comment: @scordova88 Click-Through Ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the info i needed here is what i got:

Being only test ads I cant test when it is called. I know it is called when the ad is closed with the X as i can click that in the test ad and it calls the delegate method. My question is, is it also called when the user interacts with the ad i.e clicks to download the advertised app or only when closed?

**The Delegate is called after the application is covered with an iAd and then returned to the application**

Also im trying understand the revenue from iAds.

if an ad is displayed in the bannerView on my app does that generate any revenue?

**If you show a developer iAd i.e a link to the AppStore to download an App, then you only get revenue when the iAd is clicked in the banner. If you show an iAd from a branded company i.e BMW you get revenue for having the iAd banner and more for it being clicked**

if an ad banner is clicked to load an ad does that generate any revenue?

**yes**

if an ad banner is clicked to load an ad into full screen does count towards the CTR?

**yes**

if an ad is loaded an interacted with does that generate any revenue and does that count towards the CTR?

**yes**

Thanks